# JQuery error after switching to universal theme

Tags: jquery, oracle-apex

I'm trying to move an old application from Apex 4.0.2 to Apex 19. It works fine using it's original theme but there is a problem using the Universal Theme (42).

The application uses a tooltip plugin that needs some javascript. This javascript is loaded in page 0 in an after header region.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.mytooltip').each(function() {
    var ajaxReq = new htmldb_Get(null, $v('pFlowId'),'APPLICATION_PROCESS=get_tooltip_text', $v('pFlowStepId'));
    ajaxReq.addParam('x01',$v('pFlowStepId'));
    ajaxReq.addParam('x02',$(this).attr("id"));
    ajaxReq.addParam('x03',$(this).attr("waarde"));
    var text = ajaxReq.get();
    ajaxReq=null;

    $(this).attr("title",text);
    //$(this).qtip({
    //    content: { text : text }
    //});
});
});
```

After switching to universal theme the tooltip does no longer work. I get error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.mytooltip').each(function() { <= here
```

Since the code works within the Apex 19 environment I suspect it's not the syntax itself but perhaps the order in which things are loaded. Universal theme might do things differently.

What could cause this?

Comment: this function htmldb_Get has has been desupported in Apex 5+

Comment: Is there an alternative?

Comment: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/germancommunities/apexcommunity/tipp/3341/index-en.html

Comment: maybe using this function is causing the error, are you including the jquery migrate?

Comment: It is, but in the old theme before the offending javascript and in the universal theme after. That might explain the difference in behaviour. Also thanks for the link, very usefull.

Comment: Moving #APEX_JAVASCRIPT# in the page template from the footer to the header solves the problem for now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy&Paste the inner JavaScript function `$('.mytooltip')...` without the last `... });`
2. On the page create a new dynamic action on "Page Load" with True => "Executing JavaScript Code"
3. Paste the copied part into the code section
4. Remove the older JavaScript part from you page

[image]